# Operating System not found in 14.04.3 (32bit)

Tags: system-installation, vmware

**Need Help!!**
I downloaded the ubuntu ISO file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop for 32bit.

I have try 64 bit as well - Same problem.

Install in VMware Using Typical (Recommended)
When I created the new virtual machine, in the page of choice the installer from disc image file (ISO).
**An error sign shows up:**

> Could not detect which operating system is in the disc image. You will
>   need to specify which operating system later.

I continue to click next and on the next page I choice the Guest operating system type for Linux and for Version type i choice Ubuntu. After finish the setup, I start the virtual machine. It show **Operating system not found** in the VM.

Comment: "Operating system not found" is the only message? Or does it include  more lines above it?

Answer (score 2):

> An error sign shows up: Could not detect which operating system is in the disc image. You will need to specify which operating system later.

Is NOT an error. It's just a warning.

Regarding the:

> Operating system not found

is almost always a wrongly configured VMWare. You will probably get better response on the VMWare website. A quick search shouws [this](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2505414) with the same notice ("Operating system not found") and has a solution "you need to click the "connected" and "connect at power on" in the right top corner in order to make the iso to mount properly." That topic also points to [vGeek](http://kunaludapi.blogspot.de/2012/09/vm-settings-cddvd-drive.html) on how to set up VMWare.